# how to override column names in csv file with custom schema?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file with headers and data like this:

```
Date,Transaction,Name,Memo,Amount
12/31/2018,DEBIT,Amazon stuff,24000978364666403396802,-62.48
```

I want to override the column names to be like this:

```
transaction,credit_debit,description,memo,amount
```

Here is how I manually specify the schema I want to use and then read the file:

```
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("transaction_date",  DataTypes.TimestampType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("credit_debit", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("description", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("memo", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("amount", DataTypes.DoubleType, true)
        });



        String csvPath = "input/mytransactions.csv";
        DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = spark.read();
        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = 
            dataFrameReader
            .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
            .option("header","true")
            .option("inferSchema", false)
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(csvPath);
        dataFrame.show(20);
```

But when I do, the actual column values are null when I read the file.

```
+----------------+------------+-----------+----+------+
|transaction_date|credit_debit|description|memo|amount|
+----------------+------------+-----------+----+------+
|            null|        null|       null|null|  null|
|            null|        null|       null|null|  null|
|            null|        null|       null|null|  null|
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: your schema should be equalent [`case sensitive`] to csv file columns

Comment: if your main goal is just change the column names, then after reading the csv file you can use `withColumnRenamed` function to change the column names

Comment: You can simply use `.toDF` to rename column names

Comment: In any case, the problem here is the conversion of the field `Date` as `DataTypes.TimestampType`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with Date Column and you are missing an option on csv called dateFormat.
Code below.

```
     StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("transaction_date",  DataTypes.DateType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("credit_debit", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("description", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("memo", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("amount", DataTypes.DoubleType, true)
        });
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = 
            dataFrameReader
            .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
            .option("header","true")
    .option("dateFormat", "MM/dd/YYYY")
            .option("inferSchema", false)
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(csvPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to rename the columns. This does it:

```
        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = 
                dataFrameReader
                .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
                .option("header","true")
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .csv(csvPath);

        // Rename Columns
        dataFrame = dataFrame.toDF("transaction_date","debit_credit", "description", "memo", "amount");
```